# No listen icon in Chromium

Tags: 14.04, chromium

When I use define:word in Google or using Google translate, there's suddenly no listen icon. What did happen?

Comment: This is rather unclear. Could you provide a screenshot and try to explain it better? Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Can you press an icon which produces a sound of the word when pressed? I can't on Chromium, but I can on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Like I said, you're going to have to really clarify your question.

Comment: @Seth go to google translate to translate something from english to spanish for example. can you click on listen icon and hear how the word sounds in english?

Comment: Yep, works for me.

Comment: Works for me as well on Chromium 36 aura. ([Example](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/games))

Comment: @saiarcot895 What did I do then?

Comment: Please help me guys :(

Comment: Can you see the icon in other browsers? Have you installed flash player? What plugins do you see when you type `chrome://plugins` on your chromium browser?

Comment: @Jobin, the icon in question is an <audio> tag and a base64 encoded image.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: I didn't get you, what has that to do with the comment? And anyways I can't see the <audio> tag.

Comment: @Jobin Yes, there is a flash player installed. I tried disabling it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting as an answer, because there isn't enough space in the comments:

1. Open up this link: [define:test](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=define%3Atest&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=define%3atest)
2. Right click the text that says "/test/"
3. Inspect element
4. You should see the following around the highlighted line:

```
▼<span class="lr_dct_ph">
  ▶<span>_</span>
   "/"
▶<span class="lr_dct_spkr lr_dct_spkr_off" title="Listen" jsaction="dob.p" data-log-string="pronunciation-icon-click" style="display: inline-block;">_</span>
```

The last line is the line that contains the span for both the speaker image and the audio tag for the pronunciation.  The image is base64 encoded.  If you can see [this picture of a happy bus](http://jsfiddle.net/casiano/Xadvz/) then that part is working.

If you cannot, then something is very wrong with your browser or the version you have is very old (or you have images turned off or something hard to tell or guess).

So mostly, I want to figure out if you see the last line in your html output, and if so does your browser properly display base64 encoded images.  One of these two should not be the case.

Comment: Yes, there is such code.

Comment: And do you see the happy bus?

Comment: In that case you might have an issue where a plugin is interfering.  Do you see the icon in chromium safe mode?

Comment: sorry, how? . []

Comment: I apologize, chromium doesn't have a safe mode, but if you open an incognito window it works much the same way.

Comment: It does not even show the translation in incognito.

Comment: @mrSuperEvening, what plugins do you have installed?

Comment: I tried disabling them, didn't help.